# How to use multiple lines of code for an else statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a simple number adder as part of a more complicated program. My code is part of an if-else statement.

```
else:num1=input("Enter the first number")
    num2=input("Enter the second number")
    print num1 + num2
```

However, this creates the error...

```
    num2=input("Enter the second number")
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

So how does one create a multi-line else statement?

Comment: Add a newline after the colon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put a newline after `else:` and indent all your code, as follows:

```py
else:
    num1 = input("Enter the first number")
    num2 = input("Enter the second number")
    print num1 + num2
```

Answer (score 4):

> So how does one create a multi-line else statement?

Same as any other compound statement in Python: newline, indent. Like this:

```
else:
    num1=input("Enter the first number")
    num2=input("Enter the second number")
    print num1 + num2
```

(Technically, `else` isn't a statement, it's part of an `if` statement, but let's ignore that.)

---

The actual details are explained in [Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html) in the documentation, but I don't think you want to read that unless you're trying to write your own Python parser. The basic rule is that after a colon, you can have one of these two things:

- A simple statement (one without its own colon) on the same line.
- Nothing on the rest of the line, then an indented suite of however many simple and compound statements (but at least one) you want underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
else:
    num1=input("Enter the first number")
    num2=input("Enter the second number")
    print num1 + num2
```